# How to respond to a manager if he said he is very busy and hoped he can finish work before 5?

Tags: conversation

I am not a native speaker. And I came across this situation: I came to my manager's office and reported to him about my recent work. At the end, he received an email and said something needs to be redo. He said he hoped he could leave before 5 pm this afternoon. How should I respond to him? I said "Good luck with finishing the tasks." I felt that is not appropriate.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it was _your_ fault that he had to redo something? In other words, did the manager have to redo the "something" because _you_ made a mistake? Or are your "recent work" and the "something" completely unrelated? In the first case, what you said might be inappropriate. In the second case, it seems ok.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean. Why does your boss need to finish the tasks which were assigned to you? Why does he need to do this before 5pm? Who is the boss here - him or you?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your response.

What you might say depends on your relationship with the boss. Your understanding of why he wants to leave at 5. The tone of voice that your boss used and so on.

A suggestion: "Ok I'll let you get on with it. (see you later)". As your boss is busy, but doesn't need help the best thing for you to do is to get out of his office and get back to your own work. So you finish the conversation, and the expression above would do that.